# how to call a JavaScript one function in local variable to other function

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api, function-call

I am a beginner in javascript. local variable `let searchquery = e.target.querySelector('input').value;` value is not print in fatch api `q=${searchquery}`and print the global variable value `let searchquery='';`

my output is`pizza`
`{q: "", from: 0, to: 20, more: false, count: 0, …}`

```
let searchquery='';    
searchform.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let searchquery = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
console.log(searchquery);
fetchAPI(); });

async function fetchAPI() {
const baseurl = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchquery}&app_id=${app_id}&app_key=${app_key}&to=20`;
```

Comment: Before suggestion a solution I have to ask, can't you pass the searchquery value as a parameter to the fetchAPI function?

Comment: Please share the full code, its not possible to help you with just this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `searchquery` variable twice. One outside and 2nd one inside the anonymous function of `addEventListener`. Due to this the variable scope is getting reduced and it won't be available in the `fetchAPI` method.

You should use it like this -

```
let searchquery = '';
searchform.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  searchquery = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
  console.log(searchquery);
  fetchAPI(searchquery);
});

async function fetchAPI(searchquery) {
  const baseurl = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchquery}&app_id=${app_id}&app_key=${app_key}&to=20`;
}
```

**OR**

If you need to create another variable inside submit handler, then pass this variable to `fetchAPI` as param while calling this method.

```
let searchquery = '';
searchform.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let searchquery = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
  console.log(searchquery);
  fetchAPI(searchquery);
});

async function fetchAPI(searchquery) {
  const baseurl = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchquery}&app_id=${app_id}&app_key=${app_key}&to=20`;
}
```